# How to add vertex groups to instance in geometry nodes?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

Any idea how to add *Vertex Groups* from points to instances.
My think process:

1. Get points with different *Vertex Groups* from mesh
2. Add instances to those points
3. Add *Vertex Groups* from points to instances
   and have more time on creativity

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First create a [`Vertex Group`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html) and assign vertex points to it. In my example I have created a *Vertex Group* named *MyVertexGroup* with 4 vertices assigned to it. Then drag or connect the *Selection* socket of the *Instance on Points* node to an empty socket (socket below *Geometry* socket) of the *Group Input* node which will create a new input as seen in the *Modifier Properties*. Assign the value *MyVertexGroup* to it. Notice that the instances are added only to the 4 vertices included in *MyVertexGroup*.

[image]